# Is it possible to look into research trends years and citation-wise?

Tags: publications, citations, google-scholar

Is it possible to look into research trends years and citation-wise?

---

Suppose, I look up Google Scholar and select a publication/conference, let's say ICLR: https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=en&view_op=list_hcore&venue=0032SoU2xY4J.2022&vq=eng_artificialintelligence&cstart=0

The papers are sorted from citations in the last 5 years. What I want is to see the recent trend among papers of the last 2 or 3 years which are recently published in the same conference or surf conference papers citation wise only of last 2 years. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

For the former, you can use Google Scholar's advanced search:

[image: Advanced Search screenshot]

Note, however, that Google Scholar's search results may be incomplete and noisy. For the latter, you can use [Scopus Document Search](https://www.scopus.com/search/form.uri), if you have access. Microsoft Academic used to have this feature, but has since been shut down.